# Dynamic loop in react js disturb the design

Tags: reactjs

I am getting data from the api and render it into my component  like this

```
 {this.auth.adminList.map(item => (
            <div className="item">
              <div className="pad15">
                <p className="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                <p>₹ 1</p>
                <p>₹ 6000</p>
                <p>50% off</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
```

it render in html like this
[image]

But if i give hardcode data in our array like

```
var adminList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "tu jane na",
    image: "http://localhost:5000/images/image-1594017160096.jpg",
    description: "admin",
    views: 0,
    playlistOwner: 2,
    added_at: "2020-07-07T06:22:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "adat",
    image: "http://localhost:5000/images/image-1594017160096.jpg",
    description: "admin",
    views: 0,
    playlistOwner: 2,
    added_at: "2020-07-07T06:22:10.000Z"
  }
];
```

then my html design load accurately that i want

[image]

Comment: Please include a sample of the data you get back from the API, and the code that generates the HTML (Your `this.auth.adminList..map` contains errors and will always return the same element)

Comment: two time .. before map is accidentally it's typing mistake.

Comment: Without seeing the data and code that produces the invalid output, we have no way to help solve this. (So far the question contains: A working data set, and an outline of how you use the breaking data set)